# How to intersect two sets of longs that don't fit into memory?

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, set, intersection

I've got an interesting problem. I want to intersect two Sets of Longs in Java, with each set having 1B members - this is 4GB per set. This will not fit into memory on the server that I need to run it on.

I'm wondering what interesting methods are out there for solving this problem.

What I've come up with so far is reading subsets of each original set from disk that are small enough to fit into memory, then intersecting each subset, and writing those to disk temporarily. Finally, I could go through and intersect these subsets. I get a feeling that this may turn into a map reduce job.

Maybe you'll have some better ideas :) I doubt I'm the first person to have come up with this problem.

Comment: you should look into compression methods.

Comment: 1B members? Like, 0-255? Why don't you use a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)?

Comment: Oh the joy of handling datasets too large to fit in memory - just like in the old days!

Comment: Btw `long` in Java is 64 bits, don't accidentally intersect only the first 50% of each file ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Sort both sets `A` and `B` separately.
2. Take and remove first element from set A and first element from set B
3. If they are equal, add to the result set.
4. If item from one set is greater, take next item from the second set.
5. Go to 2 as long as you don't reach end of any set.

The advantage of this method is that you never keep more then 2 longs in memory (except sorting). Sorting can be done effectively on disk (merge sort).

Comment: You should mention this requires A and B to first be individually sorted.

Comment: Note that step 1 is the tricky-ish part, an external sort, although it's tricky to figure out how to do it *well* rather than being tricky to figure out how to do it at all. It's a widely-studied problem, you can spend approximately as long as you like reading about it.

Comment: Sorting is really a battle neck in this solution, if you want to count number of disk accesses as a parameter of efficiency - it is likely to reach terrible results comparing to a hash based alternative. However, the sorting solution is more likely to have more sequential writes (comparing to the hash alternative) - if you have at least two disks.

Comment: @amit: you don't need two disks. An external merge only needs to do approximately `2 * (size of data to merge / size of RAM available to buffer)` seeks for each merge step. Since each element participates in about `log n` merge steps, there's not all that much seeking even with only one disk. Certainly far less than the "obvious" way to build an external hashtable via random access. But of course you'd cache when writing hash buckets too.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Using 1 disk instead of two approximately doubles the #seeks - since each time you need to write your just calculated buffer - the moving arm is on the data from previous iteration (the input to the current iteration) - so you will need to move it for each time you are going to write the data to disk, while using 2 disks - the writing phase is sequential and there is need to move the arm only when reading the next chunk to buffer. (Hope my calculations are not wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Do a disk-based merge sort on both sets.

Once that's done you can simply go through the sorted files sequentially and record the intersections in a new file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think can be done. Obviously put on disk.You got to sort them.

1. Sort them using [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting)
2. compare,

   ```
   if a. length < 1 or b.length < 1
     exit
   else if a[0] == b[0]
     addToIntersectionSet(a[0])
     remove a[0] from a
     remove b[0] from b
   else if a[0] < b[0]
      remove a[0]
   else 
     remove b[0]
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize 2 big bit maps to zero (bitmap1 and bitmap2) in memory if available or disk.
for each value in set1, set the value-th bitmap1 position to 1.
for each value in set2, read value-th position in bitmap1 bit and if 1, set bitmap2 at value-th position to 1.
for each set bit value in bitmap2, output value of that position.

Edit: Jessop below in replies points out the flaw: it's Java 64 bit (8 byte) long ints, not 32 bit architecture C compiler 4 byte long ints.  This solution is impractical with 64 bit longs.

Comment: This is probably the fastest option if he has 1 GB free for the two bitmaps... and one of the slowest, even with `mmap`'ing, if he hasn't. (Loading a single map from set A and comparing it with set B will also work and need 512 MB; maybe that's feasible. I'll upvote that :-) ).

Comment: Although the questioner doesn't mention this, `long` in Java is a 64 bit signed integer type. So nobody has enough memory, but maybe the questioner is mistaken and actually has `int`s.

Comment: Agreed, it's only going to be practical for 4 byte long ints, not 8 byte long ints as specified in Java.

Answer (score 2):

A possibly more efficient way then sorting is to use hashing, and split the data into several bins - and do an intersection on each bin. **The idea is to split the problem into subproblems that do fit in memory** - and then you can do the intersection efficiently on RAM.

Let's say you want to find the intersection of R,S:

```
for each element in R:
   write element in bucket_R[hash(element) % NUM_BUCKETS]
for each element in S:
   write element in bucket_S[hash(element) % NUM_BUCKETS]

//assuming each bucket from bucket_S or bucket_R now fits memory - proceed.
//if it doesn't, you can repeat the previous step with a new hash function.
for each i from 0 to NUM_BUCKETS:
  find bucket_S INTERSECTION bucket_R
```

**IMPORTANT:**

bucket_S,bucket_R or on DISK and not in RAM.

**Number of disk accesses:**

The total number of disk reads with this approach is `3 * (|R|+|S|)`

1. reading each element in R and S while iterating the first two loops
2. Writing each element to the hash table
3. reading all the buckets

While any sorting-based algorithm is most likely to need more then 1 read + 1 write (and an extra traversal on the data) - which will yield much MORE then `3 * (|R|+|S|)`

---

P.S. I am at the moment studying for a Files-System exam (which will take place on Monday), and the lecture notes says that this is the prefered solution in most data base systems, assuming you have one disk.

Answer (score 1):

This does feel like a map reduce job, but you have to be very careful about the subsets you choose. If you want your intersection to work, subsets from original sets must be cut at the same points. For example, suppose you have sets

```
A = {1 3 7 9}
B = {2 7 8 9}
```

And you cut them into two subsets each:

```
A1 = {1 3} A2 = {7 9}
B1 = {2 7} B2 = {8 9}
```

Then you intersect:

```
C1 = A1 inter B1 = {}
C2 = A2 inter B2 = {9}
```

You then suppose that:

```
C = A inter B = C1 union C2 = {9}
```

Which is obviously wrong. For your map reduce to work, you have to cut sets using some constant value, for instance A1 and B1 will contain values <5 and A2 and B2 values >=5.

You can also fetch regular parts of sets A and B from your disk and then intersect them in an intelligent way, which means looking at sorted elements incrementally and stopping when you get to the end of one of the two subsets. At that moment, you fetch an extra subset part.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing that comes to mind is starting out with sorted sets on disk. Then you can simultaneously read from both files, find matches and write them out. Say you read 204 from one file, you'd read from the other until the first number >= 204. At that point you know whether this particular number belongs to the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step might be to sort each set; sort smaller blocks & merge sort to build sorted files.

Once sorted, you can walk through both sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily keep 512 files open, so you can pre-browse both sets into 256 chunks on disk, at most 16M items, sizing 64 megabytes each. You can do this based on the most significant byte of each Long, from set.A.00 to set.B.ff

Then you can load each corresponding pair of chunks (`set.A.42` containing Longs starting with 0x42 corresponds to `set.B.42`) and use them to initialize a 16M Byte array - you initialize it to all 0s, and when you read the value `i` from the first chunk, you increment index i-th). Then you read in the second chunk, but this time incrementing by 2.

Upon completion, you do a scan of the array; 0 means the value was not present in either chunk, 1 means it was present only in the first set, 2 only in the second, 3 in both. And write the results to the result file.

You need no sorting, even if the result file will be sorted (since you'll check the chunks in order, and do the final scan in order).

This all runs in O(n) (all steps run in linear time) and requires at most 16M of RAM.

If 512 open files are too much, you can use the first 7 most significant bits and use 256 open files and 32M of RAM. Or 128 open files and 64M of RAM, and so on.

It is also possible (and maybe more efficient, if the filesystem cache isn't too good) to keep a series of 256 "buckets", each 16384 `Longs` in size (so it's again 16M). When a bucket approaches full, you open the corresponding chunk file on disk, dump the 16384 `Long`s found so far, and close the file. Then do the same for the set B. You end up with 512 files containing from 0 (unlikely) to 16 million `Long`s, never having kept open more than two files at a time.